# Extreme wait-time when taking a SQL Server database offline

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, performance

I'm trying to perform some offline maintenance (dev database restore from live backup) on my dev database, but the 'Take Offline' command via SQL Server Management Studio is performing **extremely** slowly - on the order of 30 minutes plus now. I am just about at my wits end and I can't seem to find any references online as to what might be causing the speed problem, or how to fix it.

Some sites have suggested that open connections to the database cause this slowdown, but the only application that uses this database is my dev machine's IIS instance, and the service is stopped - there are no more open connections.

What could be causing this slowdown, and what can I do to speed it up?

Answer (score 452, accepted):

After some additional searching (new search terms inspired by gbn's answer and u07ch's comment on KMike's answer) I found this, which completed successfully in 2 seconds:

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

#### (Update)

When this still fails with the following error, you can fix it as inspired by [this blog post](http://blog.degree.no/2013/03/long-wait-time-when-taking-sql-server-database-offline/):

> ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'dbname' Try again later.

you can run the following command to find out who is keeping a lock on your database:

```
EXEC sp_who2
```

And use whatever `SPID` you find in the following command:

```
KILL <SPID>
```

Then run the `ALTER DATABASE` command again. It should now work.

Comment: If this is not working (a lock could not be placed), also try the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673065.

Comment: If Take DB Offline process is still running, for dev machines you can kill it from Task Manager and run above command.

Comment: If you run the KILL command and get the message "Cannot use KILL to kill your own process.", make sure you are using master database to run the command

Comment: What's really annoying about this is that 99% of the time, allowing a connection to block taking the DB off-line is unwanted behavior. When I want the DB off-line, I want any connections to be cut.

Answer (score 133):

There is most likely a connection to the DB from somewhere (a rare example: [asynchronous statistic update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397(SQL.90).aspx))

To find connections, use [sys.sysprocesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881(SQL.90).aspx)

```
USE master
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE dbid = DB_ID('MyDB')
```

To force disconnections, use [ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269(SQL.90).aspx)

```
USE master
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: +1 because the process query lets you know what's connected to this database. in my case it was a rogue employee with SSMS open :)

Comment: In my case I was the rogue with a query analyzer window open

Comment: In my case the developers had a production main website for a very well known  bank pointing at a database lebelled OLD

Comment: If it says `ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database` command `KILL <SPID>` will help

Answer (score 32):

Do you have any open SQL Server Management Studio windows that are connected to this DB?

Put it in single user mode, and then try again.

Comment: ALTER DATABASE <DBNAME> SET SINGLE_USER WITH Rollback Immediate

Comment: KMike - the only connection I have is open to the Master database, not the database I'm trying to take offline.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, after waiting so much for it to finish I had no patience and simply closed management studio. Before exiting, it showed the success message, db is offline. The files were available to rename.

Answer (score 7):

execute the stored procedure
sp_who2

This will allow you to see if there is any blocking locks.. kill their  should fix it.

Answer (score 5):

In SSMS: right-click on SQL server icon, Activity Monitor. Open Processes. Find the processed connected. Right-click on the process, Kill.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had looked at some tables in the DB prior to executing this action. My user account was holding an active connection to this DB in SSMS. Once I disconnected from the server in SSMS (leaving the 'Take database offline' dialog box open) the operation succeeded.

Comment: Same with me. Then I reconnected, changed the active database to master and run the following command: ALTER DATABASE XXX SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 4):

anytime you run into this type of thing you should always think of your transaction log.  The alter db statment with rollback immediate indicates this to be the case.  Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085.aspx

Bone up on checkpoints, etc. You need to decide if the transactions in your log are worth saving or not and then pick the mode to run your db in accordingly.  There's really no reason for you to have to wait but also no reason for you to lose data either - you can have both.

Comment: Sage advice - thank you - but in this case the data is expendable as it's a development database that is being restored to.

Answer (score 3):

Closing the instance of SSMS (SQL Service Manager) from which the request was made solved the problem for me.....

Answer (score 3):

Also, close any query windows you may have open that are connected to the database in question ;)

Answer (score 2):

To get around this I stopped the website that was connected to the db in IIS and immediately the 'frozen' 'take db offline' panel became unfrozen.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the suggestions below and nothing worked.

1. EXEC sp_who
2. Kill < SPID >
3. ALTER DATABASE  SET SINGLE_USER WITH Rollback Immediate

   ALTER DATABASE  SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

   Result: Both the above commands were also stuck.

4 . Right-click the database -> Properties -> Options
   Set Database Read-Only to True
   Click 'Yes' at the dialog warning SQL Server will close all connections to the database.

Result: The window was stuck on executing.

As a last resort, I restarted the SQL server service from configuration manager and then ran ALTER DATABASE  SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE. It worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS, set the database to read-only then back. The connections will be closed, which frees up the locks.

In my case there was a website that had open connections to the database. This method was easy enough:

1. Right-click the database -> Properties -> Options
2. Set `Database Read-Only` to True
3. Click 'Yes' at the dialog warning SQL Server will close all connections to the database.
4. Re-open Options and turn read-only back off
5. Now try renaming the database or taking it offline.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just had to go into the Job Activity Monitor and stop two things that were processing.  Then it went offline immediately.  In my case though I knew what those 2 processes were and that it was ok to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the database was related to an old Sharepoint install. Stopping and disabling related services in the server manager "unhung" the take offline action, which had been running for 40 minutes, and it completed immediately.

You may wish to check if any services are currently utilizing the database.

Comment: Run `sp_who2` to see what processes are using the database and use `kill <PID>` to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, from the Take Offline dialog, remember to check the 'Drop All Active Connections' checkbox.  I was also on SQL_EXPRESS on local machine with no connections, but this slowdown happened for me unless I checked that checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS, especially if running it from your own desktop remotely and not directly within the database server, can be a reason for the long delays in detaching a database. For some reason SSMS may not be able to disconnect any existing "connections" to the database.

We found the process was almost instant when we did it directly from the database server itself. And in fact it killed the attempt from my own desktop SSMS session, and it "took over" and detached the database.

Nothing else suggested here worked.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my case i stopped Tomcat server . then immediately the DB went offline .