# ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database ‘DBNAME’

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. My situation appears to be different to others [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673065/alter-database-failed-because-a-lock-could-not-be-placed-on-database), [link](https://sqlzealots.com/2017/03/18/alter-database-failed-because-a-lock-could-not-be-placed-on-database-dbname-try-again-later-in-sql-server/) as I have **no active connections** to that database as reported by `sp_who2`.

The physical `.MDF` and `.LDF` files are present but I cannot take the database offline or anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can mandate the priority of your transaction with regards to deadlocks...

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10
```

So put that at the top of your alter DB statement.

```
USE [master]
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10
ALTER DATABASE
...
GO
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that.... @charithsuminda its a production server so I am attempting to find a solution that does not restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you restart the Sql server service and try to do it as soon as it started. I had a simillar issue but solve by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Sql Service or Restart Sql Server Machine we had simillar issue few months ago