# SQL Server alter database with rollback immediate

Tags: sql-server, rollback, alter-table

Sometimes when (for example) setting a database offline by executing the following command, an exception will be thrown, because one or more clients is connected:

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET OFFLINE
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808313/2874896) one solution is to use `with rollback immediate` at the end:

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

But why is actually this disconnecting other clients? It sounds like a very non-obvious way to force disconnections, although it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't take the database offline while other Users have transactions running on it so you're going to have to disconnect the users one way or another to take the database offline.

If you were being polite you could ask all your users to finish doing whatever they were doing before you took the database offline

but if that's not practical including the option

```
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Means that all current transactions are Rolled back (the database is reset to the point where the transaction started) . You could also use

```
WITH ROLLBACK AFTER 60 SECONDS
```

but I've never had to

If you could take a database offline while there were unfinished transactions were running then the database would be in an unstable state with the change neither made nor cancelled

Comment: So `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` will rollback all transactions and implicitly disconnect them?

Comment: this option will rollback all uncommited trunsactions and reset all connections, except current

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682(v=sql.105).aspx)

**WITH <termination>::=**

> Specifies when to roll back incomplete transactions when the database
>   is transitioned from one state to another. If the termination clause
>   is omitted, the ALTER DATABASE statement waits indefinitely if there
>   is any lock on the database. Only one termination clause can be
>   specified, and it follows the SET clauses.

Where termination would be `ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` in your case.

Comment: I know that `with rollback immediate`indeed does rollback any changes if an error occurs, but i'm wondering *why* it disconnects the clients. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Because clients can't be connected to a database once it is offline.

Which means that you can't take the database offline without disconnecting the clients first (That's why it throws an exception).

Which means you need to drop the connections one way or another before taking the database offline